# Converting a hexadecimal number to hexadecimal escaped character array

Tags: c, escaping, string-formatting, shellcode

I am trying to create a shellcode where I want the user to pass an integer value as port that come as an argument and later put this shellcode value along with the actual shellcode. To achieve the 1st step, I wrote this code.

1. Convert the argument to number using atoi()
2. Convert the number to host and network byte order using htons()

   `unsigned short int port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));`

   So if I pass ./a.out 9000, the port variable stores a value of 2823 ( which is a hex value of 9000)
3. My next target is to store 2823 into an character array as in an little endian, so that the character array stores the value in hex escaped format like this

   `unsigned char port[]="\x23\x28"`

So how do I convert the hexadecimal number in the port to hexadecimal escaped  string and store it into an char[] array without hardcoding?

I have seen lots of examples on printing it to "\x23\x28" format , but I have not seen any example on how to store in that format. I have already tried out using sscanf like the one below but not able to achieve the exact thing that I wanted.

`sscanf(port_shellcode,"\\x",port);`

Comment: Please dont downvote the answer, if you cannot answer the question. Down voting is easy , but giving the answer is tough.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a built-in function for this, but you could do it yourself:

```
#define CONVERT_TO_ESCAPED_HEX(n, s) \
    do { \
        char ts[100] = { '\0' }; \
        int i; \
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(n) / sizeof(char); i++) \
        { \
            sprintf(s, "\\x%02x%s", ((n >> (8 * i)) & 0xff), ts); \
            sprintf(ts, "%s", s); \
        } \
    } while(0)
...
short port = 9000;
char s[100];
CONVERT_TO_ESCAPED_HEX(port, s);
printf("%s\n", s);
```

Comment: Thanks but I found an easier way to do this ! Cheers

Comment: @Dibsyhex Then post this other way as an answer.

Comment: Posted the answer. Have a look !

Answer (score 0):

Okay Problem Solved :) I tried to do it in a different way, I changed the opcodes of the shellcode directly instead of doing this in my described approach. I split the the number into AA and BB and store them in char variables and then overwritten the location with these values. Details can be found at my github code base
https://github.com/dibsy/SLAEx86/blob/master/assignment1/shellcode_with_configurable_port.c